# Open API instead of iFrame

Tags: php

I am currently using iframes to show content on an external domain. This is causing issues as the contents height and width changes meaning I either need scrolling or set a fixed width and height.

What process would I need to take to give my users a code snippet instead of using an iframe. I am using php

Comment: Why not do borderless iframe with height that makes scrolling unnecessary(set using javascript)? kind of like this `<iframe src="http://youtube.com" frameborder='0' onload="this.width=screen.width;this.height=screen.height;">`

Comment: problem is that the height may start at 100px then get bigger to 500px. I need it to keep adjusting to the content size

Comment: Javascript will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You more likely need to build an API (PHP or Javascript) for your website so third party websites / servers may use it. Another option would be to make your iframe content responsive and control its height with javascript.